# NullPointerException when referenceing properties file

Tags: nullpointerexception, properties-file

I have the below method:

```
public String readJson(){
    String everything = "";
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/users/mypc/test/etc/one.json"))) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        everything = sb.toString();
        logger.debug("Everything: " + everything);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    logger.debug("line: " + everything);
    return everything;
}
```

This works fine as it is. My problem is that I don't want to hard code the file path /users/mypc/test/etc/one.json. I tried adding it to a properties file by doing the following:

test.properties:

```
file1=/users/mypc/test/etc/one.json
```

PropertiesHelper.java:

```
public String GET_FILE_ONE = "file1";

private static String one;

public String getJsonFile(){
    one = config.getProperty(this.GET_FILE_ONE);
    return one;
}
```

JsonReader.java:

```
private static PropertiesHelper helper;

final String GET_FILE_ONE = helper.getJsonFile();

public String readJson(){
String everything = "";
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(GET_FILE_ONE))) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    everything = sb.toString();
    logger.debug("Everything: " + everything);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
logger.debug("line: " + everything);
return everything;
}
```

I've done similar things in the past but this time I'm getting a NullPointerException. I've been staring at this for a while now and can't see what's wrong. Is there something wrong with the way I've set my file path in the properties file or is there something else I've missed?

Comment: Add the exception message so we have a better idea of what's going on. A FileNotFound exception should be thrown if the file isn't found, not a NPE. So I think your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I found the problem. Your `PropertiesHelper helper` is never created. Add in `PropertiesHelper helper  = new PropertiesHelper();`

Comment: Also, whoever downvoted the question; that isn't justified. The question is well formatted even if the solution is simple.

Comment: Ah, that was it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered above by Donnacha.

The issue was resolved by adding private static PropertiesHelper helper = new PropertiesHelper(); to JsonReader.java. See below:

```
private static PropertiesHelper helper;

private static PropertiesHelper helper = new PropertiesHelper();

final String GET_FILE_ONE = helper.getJsonFile();

public String readJson(){
    String everything = "";
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(GET_FILE_ONE))) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        everything = sb.toString();
        logger.debug("Everything: " + everything);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    logger.debug("line: " + everything);
    return everything;
}
```